# Code helpers/ Add-ons to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: ide, visual-studio-addins

I wanted to know what the public opinion is about Resharper vs Devxpress CodeRush vs Visual AssitX.

some of my co-workers are CodeRush fans.. I like Resharper...would be great if someone could finish the debate for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one can say one is better than the other. It's down to preference.

Personally, I use Resharper for the following reasons:

1. Its keyboard shortcuts allow me to code way faster, and perform numerous refactorings in no time
2. The live templates are amazing, and creating your own is a snap
3. The build in unit test runner is a must have. I couldn't live without it now

The performance in the newer versions suffers a bit, but overall it's imo the best VS addon by far.